# React- Change checkbox to be unchecked dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I have this table with these checkboxes.
When I click on "Add Entries" the right modal is being opened.
When I click on "Done", the checkboxes should become unchecked without refreshing the page.
Can you please advise me with a solution? 
[image]

```
class Home extends Component {
    selectedApps=[];
    selectedAppsObjArr=[];
       state={
        appList:[],
        isOpen:false,
        addedAppsArray:[],
       }
```

This is the function that it's content is the input checkbox

```
 chooseAppSelector=()=>
     {
        let appSelectorArray=[];
        for (let application of this.state.appList)
        {
        appSelectorArray.push(

            <tr>
            **<th scope="row"><input type="checkbox" className={"appsCheckbox"}  id={"appSelectorCheckbox"+application.id} onClick={()=>this.checkCheckbox(application.id, application)}/></th>** 
            <td>{application.product}</td>
            </tr>
        )
        }
        return appSelectorArray;
     }

    checkboxStatus=()=> `this one is a validation of the checkbox clicks and it works as needed`
    {
        `I want to change the checkboxes status in here`
    }

checkCheckbox=(appId, application)=>
     {
        let contains=this.selectedApps.includes(appId)
        if (contains==false)
            {
                this.selectedApps.push(appId)
                this.selectedAppsObjArr.push(application)
            }
            else
            {
                let index=this.selectedApps.indexOf(appId);
                this.selectedApps.splice(index,1);
                let index2=this.selectedAppsObjArr.indexOf(appId)
                this.selectedAppsObjArr.splice(index2,1);
            }
     }

  sendForm = () => {
        this.toggleModal(); `Closing the Modal Window`
        this.addNewNetworks() ` Not important function`

        this.checkboxStatus(); `the above function`
      }

render (){

  return (
<Table striped bordered hover> `the table component`
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>App</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
```

Input checkbox in "chooseAppSelector"

```
                        {this.chooseAppSelector()}
                        </tbody>
                        </Table>

`divs....`
)
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Pass a callback that clears the checkboxes to the modal. When the user clicks Done, you invoke the callback before/after doing the other things.

Comment: In your `checkboxStatus` function. Return an event and add it to your checkboxes like this: `<input
    type="checkbox"
    checked={this.state.checked}
    onChange={this.onChangeAction.bind(this)}
/>` where this.state.checked = false. then call it at an appropriate time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your Done onClick handler add this 2 line :

```
handleDone=()=>{

   var clist=document.getElementsByClassName("appsCheckbox");
   for (var i = 0; i < clist.length; ++i) { clist[i].checked = false }

}
```